# How can I convert/format a json string with bash

Tags: json, bash

I have the following `string`:

```
"{\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n  \"project_id\": \"my-project-123\",\n  \"time\": \"23:00:22.23124\"\n  }"
```

And I want a formatted `JSON` like this:

```
{
    "type":"service_account",
    "project_id":"my-project-123",
    "time":"23:00:22.23124"
}
```

Comment: What produced that string?

Comment: Are the outer quotes part of the string, i.e., do you have `x='"{\n \"type..."'` or `x="{\n \"type..."`?

Comment: The string is inside a txt file.

Comment: Did something encode a JSON value as a JSON string? You might want to use something like `jq 'fromjson' yourfile.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` option can expand `\n` within a string.

```
echo -e "put your string here"
```

Comment: `printf "%s"` ?

Comment: I suggest to replace `%s` with `%b`.

Comment: Anything that replaces `echo -e` ;)

Comment: This will expand *all* escape sequences, even if they occur inside JSON strings and should be treated literally.

Comment: @chepner: This is correct and possibly not intended.

Comment: What if I have the string in a text file? I tried using it like this:
```echo -e $(cat test.txt)``` but I get the following output:
```"{
 \"type\": \"service_account\",
 \"project_id\": \"my-project-123\",
 \"time\": \"23:00:22.23124\"
 }"```

Comment: @RickyPerez: I suggest to start a new question with this requirement.